# How to make selenium webdriver drag/click a slider on a certain value on python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a slider webelement "ID=Slider that can be dragged/clicked between the values 0%/100%. When one of the values is chosen it is shown in the the output class "value" which appears like this: "calc(7% + 6.8px)

I want selenium to click or drag the slider to a percentage value if possible.

Comment: you should add more details , a url if possible, code which you have tries mored details would help

Comment: You'll want actions' "dragAndDropBy": https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#dragAndDropBy(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,int,int)